X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded-For Headers not returning true ip? (nginx, fastapi, docker)
I am using FastAPI and nginx within a docker container. I have configured my nginx so that it should be forwarding the correct headers, however the X-Real-IP or X-Forwarded-For headers are returning IP's such as 192.xxx.xxx.1 (Censored because i'm unsure if it's sensitive or not)
NGINX Proxy Headers:
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

I have tried adding the uvicorn proxyheaders middleware, as well as changing around the headers and nginx config a bit. It is supposed to return the clients IPV4 address, however does not. It is worth noting I am running my container locally, however I am unsure if that would affect it.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!


It is worth noting I am running my container locally, however I am unsure if that would affect it.

If you run your container locally, and you access your container from any LAN devices, it's possible that it is 192.xxx.xxx.xxx as it's the IP address of your LAN device.
If you want to get the real IP address you have to access your service via internet (for example, mobile phone with 4G network). However, you have to publish you service to internet first.
